# Store data onto local disk without prompting the user

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, web, shared-objects

I have a flash application which runs on web. I need to store images and audio files onto the clients local disk(don't want to store on web) without prompting the client. I have already tried with shared object. But since shared object space is limited to 100 KB per domain I am searching for alternatives.

If someone has better solutions please let me know.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem with creating log files and writing to them

The only solution for me was to create a localhost WebService (used WCF), so i could use URLRequest to the localhost and pass data to service - which then updated file or created it.

But in your way, if you want to store things from the user to your disk, maybe you could also somehow play with the Web services. Just need to try.

Visual studio has almost complete Web service template - just edit for your purposes.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer.. but I cant use WebServices as I will be hosting this application onto web and want to save data onto users local store

Comment: So i think there is no another option to solve this problem. Flash is strictly secured with saving data. Unless it's Adobe Air. Then it is easier, because it is has methods which allows to save data without prompting.

Answer (score 2):

You can't do this with the Flash Player by itself. `SharedObject` and `FileReference/save()` are intentionally designed to allow the user to have authority over local storage. It would be a security concern if users did not.

Using an AIR application, though, you can do this using `File` and `FileStream`, or `EncryptedLocalStore`.